# How to concatenate this PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

If I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => JHN.1.1|Tun fara farawa akwai Kalma, Kalman kuwa yana nan tare da Allah, Kalman kuwa Allah ne. 
    [1] => JHN.1.2|Yana nan tare da Allah tun fara farawa.
     .
     .
     .
    [25] => JHN.1.20|Bai yi mūsu ba, amma ya shaida a fili cewa, “Ba ni ne Kiristi ba.”
 -> [26] => JHN.1.21|Sai suka tambaye shi suka ce, “To, wane ne kai? Kai ne Eliya?”
 -> [27] => JHN.1.21|Ya ce, “Aʼa, ni ba shi ba ne.”
 -> [28] => JHN.1.21|“Kai ne Annabin nan?”
 -> [29] => JHN.1.21|Ya amsa ya ce, “Aʼa.”
    [30] => JHN.1.22|A ƙarshe suka ce, “Wane ne kai? Ka ba mu amsa don mu mayar wa waɗanda suka aike mu. Me kake ce da kanka?”
```

and I would like it to become this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => JHN.1.1|Tun fara farawa akwai Kalma, Kalman kuwa yana nan tare da Allah, Kalman kuwa Allah ne. 
    [1] => JHN.1.2|Yana nan tare da Allah tun fara farawa.
     .
     .
     .
    [25] => JHN.1.20|Bai yi mūsu ba, amma ya shaida a fili cewa, “Ba ni ne Kiristi ba.”
 -> [26] => JHN.1.21|Sai suka tambaye shi suka ce, “To, wane ne kai? Kai ne Eliya?” Ya ce, “Aʼa, ni ba shi ba ne.” “Kai ne Annabin nan?” Ya amsa ya ce, “Aʼa.”
    [27] => JHN.1.22|A ƙarshe suka ce, “Wane ne kai? Ka ba mu amsa don mu mayar wa waɗanda suka aike mu. Me kake ce da kanka?”
```

What's an efficient way to concatenate the verses with multiple segments?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and build a dictionary keyed on the JHN.

```
$array = [
    "JHN.1.1|Tun fara farawa akwai Kalma, Kalman kuwa yana nan tare da Allah, Kalman kuwa Allah ne.",
    "JHN.1.2|Yana nan tare da Allah tun fara farawa.",
    "JHN.1.20|Bai yi mūsu ba, amma ya shaida a fili cewa, “Ba ni ne Kiristi ba.”",
    "JHN.1.21|Sai suka tambaye shi suka ce, “To, wane ne kai? Kai ne Eliya?”",
    "JHN.1.21|Ya ce, “Aʼa, ni ba shi ba ne.”",
    "JHN.1.21|“Kai ne Annabin nan?”",
    "JHN.1.21|Ya amsa ya ce, “Aʼa.”",
    "JHN.1.22|A ƙarshe suka ce, “Wane ne kai? Ka ba mu amsa don mu mayar wa waɗanda suka aike mu. Me kake ce da kanka?”"
];

$dict = [];

foreach ($array as $str) {
    // split string e.g. $jhn = JHN.1.1, $value = Tun fara...
    list($jhn, $value) = explode('|', $str);
    // add key to dictionary if it does not exist
    if (!isset($dict[$jhn])) {
        $dict[$jhn] = [];
    }
    // add value
    $dict[$jhn][] = $value;
}
```

Now just rebuild array using dictionary.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($dict as $jhn => $values) {
    $result[] = $jhn . '|' . implode(' ', $values);
}
```

Note: this will fail if you have more than one | in each string. If so, then you will need to use regular expression or something else to split the string.